# How to print something in typescript when a search form change?

Tags: typescript

Here is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
    <body>
        <input type="search" id="site-search" name="q"
       aria-label="Search through site content" onchange="onChange()">
    <script id="search_js" src="compiled/search.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my search.ts file :

```
  const search : HTMLElement | null  = document.getElementById("site-search");
  function onChange(event: any) {
    search.innerText = "toto";
    search.textContent = "toto";
    console.log("titi");

  }
console.log("toto);
```

I would like to use the function onChange in my typescript code whenever something is typed in the search field.

Here is a sample codepen demo :

https://codepen.io/bussiere/pen/vYgjaej

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will notice in your codepen link that the `onchange` event gets fired when you finish editing the textbox and remove the focus.

To run your callback as the user is editing the textbox, you can listen to the `onkeup` event of the `<input />` element, which will get fired on every keystroke in the text box.